# ElasticSearch max shard size

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to configure my elasticsearch cluster but I need more information.
I understand rules to choose the number of shard to use.
What I don't know is the maximum size of a shard. Is it link this the JVM max size or another param?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rule of thumb** is to not have a shard larger than 30-50GB. But this number depends on the use case, your acceptable query response times, your hardware etc.

You need to test this and establish this number. There is no hard rule for how large a shard can be. Take one node from the cluster, create the index with one primary and no replicas and add to it as many documents as you can. Test your queries. If you are happy with the response times, add more document. Test again. And so on. When the response times are not satisfactory anymore, this is your **hardware** limit for a shard size.

Don't forget that this number might be lower if the use-case requires it (many shards on a single node, huge number of concurrent requests per second, configuration mistakes etc).

In conclusion: test as indicated above and you get an "ideal" shard size as a starting point.

Comment: E.g. no limits?

Comment: @Cherry There is a practical limit, if you want. Also, there is a theoretical maximum limit of 2147483519 documents in a single shard.